# how to display ticket where i want data from booking page in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In the previous page i filled payment details and submited and it shows train booked and i want to print ticket but im not getting data of the present booking .i tried to get data with booking_id but its not retrieving data.i can get retrieve data with passenger_id but it is not unique bcz one user can book multiple trains so it shows first entry in the database if there are multiple entries by one passenger .but im not being to get data with booking_id.help me!!!!!!

```js
 model
       public function viewtrain($booking_id=null)
      {
        if($booking_id)
        { 
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('booked');
        $this->db->where('booking_id=?');
        $alltrains=$this->db->get();
        return $alltrains->result();
       }
       }
```

```css
view
  

  <table class="table table-type  " style="text-align:center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Train ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Origin</th>
      <th scope="col">Destination</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Arrival Time</th>
      <th scope="col">Departure Time</th>
      <th scope="col">Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php if(count($alltrains)):?>
    <?php foreach($alltrains as $alltrain): ?>
    <tr class="table-type">
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->booking_id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->origin; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->destination; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->date; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->arrivaltime; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->departuretime; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->class; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $alltrain->price; ?></td>
      <td>
          <?php echo anchor("admin/edittrain/{$alltrain->train_id}",'Edit',['class'=>'btn btn-outline-primary','style'=>'font-size:15px;height:20px;width:40%;padding-top :0px;']); ?>
          <?php echo anchor("admin/deletetrain/{$alltrain->train_id}",'Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-outline-danger','style'=>'font-size:15px;height:20px;width:50%;padding-top :0px;']); ?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  <?php else:?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><h4>NO Trains Available!!</h4></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endif;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
Controller

        public function ticket($booking_id=null)
        {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $alltrains=$this->user_model->viewtrain($booking_id);
        $this->load->view('ticket',['alltrains'=>$alltrains]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is not being retrieved because the format is wrong in your model, I've written the correct format below, see if this helps you. 
**Model**

```
 if($booking_id)
 { 
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('booked');
     $this->db->where('booking_id', $booking_id);
     $alltrains=$this->db->get();

     return $alltrains->result();
 }
```

Comment: still the same..it is empty..not showing up any data

Comment: Are you sure that `$booking_id` is not empty?

Comment: yes ofcourse .i think i should set booking_id to session.but how?

Comment: If booking_id is not empty it, the query should work just fine. Do `print_r($alltrains);` in your `controller` to see, if it has any value.

Comment: it displays array() which is empty..im confused

Comment: This could mean two things- 1. The condition you're applying returns no data(empty). 2. the `$booking_id` is empty. 
`echo $booking_id;` see if it has any value.